# How To Open The Filter SubMenu Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access, filter, vba

I was wondering if there is a way using either VBA or even a keyboard shortcut to open the filter submenu, the default one that appears when you click filter in the ribbon. This is the one that appears the same in Microsoft Excel when you filter a column.

My need is that for the end user they have requested that the ribbon and navigation pane are completely hidden. I am aware of the usual way to apply a filter using vba however, the default submenu is so much more user friendly!

Many thanks in advance

Tom

Comment: If you choose to hide the ribbon, you wont be able to show a part of it to the user, even in VBA. However the "filter menu" still appears in contextual menu (right-click), is it not sufficient ?

Comment: Hi, the filter menu when right clicking a form only allows you to type the filter parameter. Example right click, select text filters, select equals, type parameter. I wish to view list that appears when you filter in excel for example allowing you to select the values to include.

Comment: Could you use a subform that's requeried after selecting a listbox? Essentially replacing the filter submenu with the listbox and using VBA to filter the results in the subform?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes I could! I could open a popup form on the text box's onclick event and then populate it with all possible values. It just seems strange there wouldn't be a keyboard shortcut or anything! its so frustrating that when the ribbon is visible I can see the Filter icon and click it and yet I have no way of doing so using a keyboard

Comment: This is a bit over my head, but can't you edit the right-click menu that is only allowing a parameter entry? I think it has to do with commandbars, but I have zero experience using them. (http://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/12904/Understanding-and-using-CommandBars-Part-II-Creating-your-own.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in the end! The trick was to add this:

`DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdFilterMenu`

to an event, onclick, bdlclick etc.

Thank you all for your help!

Tom

Forum I found the answer on:

http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=199891